# How to Generate Google C++ Unit Test XML Report for total project in vc++

Tags: c++, xml

i want to generate an xml file for my project which uses Google C++ testing. if my project is present in c:\projects\XYZ\XYZUnitTest\XYZUnitTestD.exe.
in this case how can i export my Gtest outputs into XML file. i want all classes test results in one XML file. if i add any new also it should update those results.

Comment: that day i was able to see the tests details total tests. but now im not able to see. and i recreated, then also im not able to see the xml output :( what should i do????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i got it with by setting it in environmental variables.